# How to activate trial subscription of monthly subscription (auto-renewing)?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I created a monthly subscription (auto-renewing) and installed a trial of 14 days for it in the App Store Connect. How to activate it now? I want that immediately after registering the user in the application a window appears with a proposal to purchase a monthly subscription or take advantage of the 14-day free version. How to use it in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether or not your subscription has introductory period. You need to implement:
1. products fetching using SKProductsRequest:

```swift
func loadProducts(){
    let request = SKProductsRequest.init(productIdentifiers: productIds)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {                
    products = response.products
}
```

2. initiate payment process of that product using SKPaymentQueue:

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

3. Handle each switch-case in updated transactions method:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                // handle here
                break
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                // handle here
                break
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                // handle here
                break
            case .deferred, .purchasing:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

More details you can read in my article: https://blog.apphud.com/swift-tutorial-subscriptions/

You can also use the [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) library.